# MQ error code 2058 when connecting to queue manager JMS

Tags: queue, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to Queue Manager using MQ api and I am able to connect to queue manager

```
MQQueueManager queueManager=new MQQueueManager(qmgrName);
queueManager.accessQueue(qName,MQOO_OUTPUT);
```

But when I try to connect to the same queue manager using JMS it fails with 2058 code.Not sure if I am missing something with JMS

```
    MQQueueConnectionFactory qcf=new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    qcf.setQueueManager(qmgrName);
    qcf.setPort(1414);
    qcf.setHostname("localhost");
    qcf.createQueueConnection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two or more queue managers on the local host.  In your first example you connect in bindings mode so the queue manager is selected by name and you get the right one.  In the second example the connection is being made over a client connection and so is received by the QMgr listening on 1414 which is not the one that you intend so the connection is rejected.

Please note that if both QMgrs have a listener on 1414 the connection will succeed or fail depending on which QMgr was started first.  Only one can bind to that port so the first one started on it gets to use it.  This might lead to what appears to be inconsistent behavior.

Please see [Connection modes for IBM MQ classes for JMS](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031720_.htm) which advises "To change the connection options used by the IBM MQ classes for JMS, modify the Connection Factory property `CONNOPT`."  The acceptable values are provided on the page but you almost always want it to set for Standard Bindings (`MQCNO_STANDARD_BINDING`).

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041280_.htm), MQRC 2058 means an invalid queue manager name or the queue manager name is unknown. But as you mention, bindings mode connection using MQ Base Java is successful, the queue manager name appears valid.

**Update:**

Sorry, I was mislead by your code and thought you are trying to do client mode connection using JMS. You don't need to set host and port for bindings mode connection.

Since the transport type is not set, default, WMQ_CM_BINDINGS is used. Suggest you to verify the queue manager name.

Comment: I am trying to connect using Binding mode only in JMS.But it still fails

Answer (score 1):

To connect with "BINDINGS", the queue manager needs to be local.  Are you trying to connect to a remote queue manager?  If so you would need to connect as "CLIENT".  Also, check to be sure the qmgr is listening on the port you specified.